# javascript pubnub messaging system

Tags: pubnub

I am currently using PubNub SDK for chatting in website and iPhone. Now i want to implement functionality like i want to send message from iPhone to web-end once user sends a message from iPhone to web-end ( user will be notified ).

Now the issue is when initially user1 sends message from iPhone to webend i am not getting notification.

on first message i am not getting notification.

code is somewhat like this

```
var socket = new WebSocket("Pubnub + channel1id";
var chat_socket = new WebSocket("Pubnub + channel2id";
socket.onmessage = function (evt)
 {
    //Here i implemeted our notification functionality.
 }  

 chat_socket.onmessage = function (evt)
 {
    //Here i implemeted our notification functionality.
 }
```

on second message i am getting object on .onmessage but not for first.

Comment: Why are you using our WebSockets SDK? Why not use the PubNub JavaScript SDK in your Web app? There is no advantage gained by using the WebSocket SDK. But to your issue, this snippet of code is not enough to troubleshoot. Can you send your full web app zipped/attached to [PubNub Support](https://pubnub.com/support) for review/troubleshooting?

Comment: @CraigConover all the things are working fine by using pubnub + WebSockets, the issue i am facing is the first message sent from iphone to web app has not received anywhere after loading the particular message i am getting  every message in 


var socket = new WebSocket("pubnuburl" + channel_id);
socket.onmessage = function (evt) {
//under the evt i am getting message something like this //evt.data['pn_other'];
}

Not on very first message by iphone why??

Comment: Difficult to impossible to troubleshoot without more info. Can you send your full web app zipped/attached to [PubNub Support] (https://pubnub.com/support) for review/troubleshooting?